# How do I apply conditions on a particular group element and find permutations from another group in the same table?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have the following data.frame

```
  Category Product Status
1        A     qwe     In
2        A     rty     In
3        A     ewq    Out
4        B     dfs     In
5        B     sgf     In
6        C     mnb    Out
7        C     ves    Out
8        C     klm    Out
9        C     nbc    Out
```

My goal is to create a column **Flag** per group from the **Category** where the levels are ***OnlyIn, OnlyOut*** and ***BothInOut***, corresponding to the values from the **Status** Column.

As a part of it I calculated Counts on In and Out per group using the below code:

```
Data <- Data %>% 
  group_by(Category,Status) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(InCounts = length(Status[Status == "in"]),
                OutCounts = length(Status[Status == "out"]))
```

And I got the below result :

```
  Category Product Status CountIn CountOut
1        A     qwe     In       2        0
2        A     rty     In       2        0
3        A     ewq    Out       0        1
4        B     dfs     In       2        0
5        B     sgf     In       2        0
6        C     mnb    Out       0        4
7        C     ves    Out       0        4
8        C     klm    Out       0        4
9        C     nbc    Out       0        4
```

Now, I'm not sure on how to leverage this information to create the new column Flag by counting the total In and Out per Category and add an appropriate value.

Example, if there are both in and out as status for a Category, then the Flag should read "BothInOut"

Sample Output :

```
  Category Product Status CountIn CountOut      Flag
1        A     qwe     In       2        0 BothInOut
2        A     rty     In       2        0 BothInOut
3        A     ewq    Out       0        1 BothInOut
4        B     dfs     In       2        0    OnlyIn
5        B     sgf     In       2        0    OnlyIn
6        C     mnb    Out       0        4   OnlyOut
7        C     ves    Out       0        4   OnlyOut
8        C     klm    Out       0        4   OnlyOut
9        C     nbc    Out       0        4   OnlyOut
```

---

Reproducible Input for Data

```
structure(list(Category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), Product = c("qwe", "rty", "ewq", "dfs", "sgf", "mnb", 
"ves", "klm", "nbc"), Status = c("In", "In", "Out", "In", "In", 
"Out", "Out", "Out", "Out"), CountIn = c(2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0), CountOut = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4), Flag = c("BothInOut", 
"BothInOut", "BothInOut", "OnlyIn", "OnlyIn", "OnlyOut", "OnlyOut", 
"OnlyOut", "OnlyOut")), .Names = c("Category", "Product", "Status", 
"CountIn", "CountOut", "Flag"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Category) %>% mutate(Flag1 = toString(unique(Status)))`

Comment: That's done, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref to @Sotos comment :

```
Data <- Data %>% group_by(Category) %>% mutate(Flag1 = toString(unique(Status)))

Data$Flag <- ifelse(Data$Flag1 == "In","OnlyIn",
                    ifelse(Data$Flag1 == "Out","OnlyOut","BothInOut"))
```

Gets the work done.

```
  Category Product Status   Flag1     Flag2
1        A     qwe     In In, Out BothInOut
2        A     rty     In In, Out BothInOut
3        A     ewq    Out In, Out BothInOut
4        B     dfs     In      In    OnlyIn
5        B     sgf     In      In    OnlyIn
6        C     mnb    Out     Out   OnlyOut
7        C     ves    Out     Out   OnlyOut
8        C     klm    Out     Out   OnlyOut
9        C     nbc    Out     Out   OnlyOut
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say @Sotos comment does it fine, another approach to get the exact labels you want would be

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(Flag2 = ifelse("In" %in% unique(Status) & "Out" %in% unique(Status), "BothInOut", ifelse("In" %in% unique(Status), "OnlyIn", "OnlyOut")))

> df
Source: local data frame [9 x 7]
Groups: Category [3]

# A tibble: 9 x 7
  Category Product Status CountIn CountOut      Flag     Flag2
     <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <chr>     <chr>
1        A     qwe     In       2        0 BothInOut BothInOut
2        A     rty     In       2        0 BothInOut BothInOut
3        A     ewq    Out       0        1 BothInOut BothInOut
4        B     dfs     In       2        0    OnlyIn    OnlyIn
5        B     sgf     In       2        0    OnlyIn    OnlyIn
6        C     mnb    Out       0        4   OnlyOut   OnlyOut
7        C     ves    Out       0        4   OnlyOut   OnlyOut
8        C     klm    Out       0        4   OnlyOut   OnlyOut
9        C     nbc    Out       0        4   OnlyOut   OnlyOut
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to make @Sotos comment more robust, i.e. the order of the label should not depend on the order in the data by adding `sort`:

```
df %>% group_by(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Flag1 = toString(sort(unique(Status)))
```

If you want to have the data labelled as you suggested it, you can extend it to:

```
df %>% group_by(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Flag1 = paste0(sort(unique(Status)), collapse = "") %>% 
                 paste0(ifelse(. == "InOut", "Both", "Only"), .))
```

Which yields:

```
  Category Product Status CountIn CountOut      Flag     Flag1
     <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <chr>     <chr>
1        A     qwe     In       2        0 BothInOut BothInOut
2        A     rty     In       2        0 BothInOut BothInOut
3        A     ewq    Out       0        1 BothInOut BothInOut
4        B     dfs     In       2        0    OnlyIn    OnlyIn
5        B     sgf     In       2        0    OnlyIn    OnlyIn
6        C     mnb    Out       0        4   OnlyOut   OnlyOut
7        C     ves    Out       0        4   OnlyOut   OnlyOut
8        C     klm    Out       0        4   OnlyOut   OnlyOut
9        C     nbc    Out       0        4   OnlyOut   OnlyOut
```